# Прошедшее и настоящее время

Tags: времена

Возможно ли такое сочетание времен: "Мне сразу понравилось это место. Большой сад, где цветы рассказывали мне истории, которые доносятся до них со всего света". Хочется сказать о том, что истории рассказывали в прошлом, но доносятся они до них и сейчас тоже.

Comment: Звучит отлично. Погоня за двойной точностью будет идти в ущерб слогу: "Большой сад, где цветы рассказывали мне истории, что и поныне доносятся до них со всего света."

Comment: Спасибо, значит она хорошо звучит и в первоначальном варианте, и в вашем?

Comment: Да, но если придираться, то истории которые вам рассказывали будут другими, нежели те, что доносятся и поныне. А из грамматики следует, что одни и те же.

Comment: Подумаю над этим) Спасибо